# Calculating the std dev of a 30 team league with each team having a 50% chance of winning

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

I just want to preface this with the fact it is not a home work question.  I am also not a stats person so I am not sure even how to start with calculating this, what it is called or where to look.  When I google I get not much that looks like it helps.

So my problem, assume you have a 30 team league.  Any game between two teams has a 50% chance of winning or losing, essentially a coin flip.  I know that at the end of the runs all the teams wont have equal amount of wins, you'll get a normal distribution or bell curve.

How do I calculate what the standard deviations of the win% for each team would be?  Let's assume 500 games.

How would I solve this? How would I even start?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the number of wins for team $i$ alone (we can convert that to a percentage at the end, by dividing by the number of games and multiplying by 100).

From your statements the results for the other teams have the same distribution by symmetry (though the realizations will be different because of random variation).

For team $i$, we have:

- The team plays $n$ games.
- each game it has a 50% chance of winning
- the outcome of each game is independent of the outcome of every other game

The outcome of a single game is a [$\text{Bernoulli}(p)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) random variable, where $p = 0.5$ - i.e. a metaphorical 'coin toss'.

The distribution of the number of wins for team $i$ is therefore [$\text{binomial}(n, 0.5)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

The standard deviation of a $\text{binomial}(n, p)$ is $\sqrt{n p (1-p)}$ so the standard deviation of the number of wins for team $i$ is $\sqrt{n/4}$.

The *proportion* of wins is just a scaled binomial, where the count is multiplied by $1/n$.

That means the standard deviation of the proportion of wins is $\frac{\sqrt{n/4}}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n}}$.

The *percentage* of wins is just a scaled binomial, where the count is multiplied by $100/n$.

That means the standard deviation of the percentage of wins for team $i$ is $\frac{100}{\sqrt{4n}}=\frac{5}{\sqrt{n}}\%$.

Your $n=500$, so:

- the number of wins has mean 250 and standard deviation 11.2
- the proportion of wins has mean 0.5 and standard deviation 0.0224
- the percentage of wins has mean 50% and standard deviation 2.24%

[image: percentage of wins for team i]

Note that the results of teams $i$ and $j$ are not independent, however, so if you start looking as sums of wins or differences of wins over more than one team, you have to take that into account. Similarly, if you combine the distributions across teams, even though the individual marginal distributions are all the same, there will be slightly more 'structure' to the combined results than you'd see from a random sampling of the individual distribution. (The mean and standard deviation of the number of wins will be fixed, for example.)

---

### Results for an 82-game season:

A regular season has $n=82$, so:

- the number of wins has mean 41 and standard deviation 4.53
- the proportion of wins has mean 0.5 and standard deviation 0.0552
- the percentage of wins has mean 50% and standard deviation 5.52%

[image: percent of wins in 82-game season]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense.  I was trying to recreate this http://www.arcticicehockey.com/2010/11/22/1826590/luck-in-the-nhl-standings using the authors instructors.  I calculated all the win % of the teams over a subset of seasons and with excel got a std of 0.09346346.  The results aren't close to the authors 38%

Comment: That link doesn't say how many games he simulated. How do you know what the $n$ is? Also note that the 38% he mentions is *not the standard deviation*.

Comment: Reading around, it looks to me like the 2011-12 regular season was only 82 games for each team. Would he have used an $n$ of about that size? It produces results almost identical to his green curve (except it shouldn't be drawn as a curve).

Comment: with the exception of this season (strike shortened), 82 games is the normal length of a hockey season.

Comment: @ClarkW.Griswold Thanks for the confirmation. Then it seems weird for the OP to be asking us to use n=500; he would almost certainly have simulated a regular season. I have now included the results for an 82-game season. I can only hope the OP will check back.

Comment: I was thinking 7 seasons @ 82 games which is 574, I just simplified it to 500.  The author in that blog either did it on 1 season or did it on 5 I am not sure.  The 38% is the % difference between the calculated s.d of normal distribution of win% vs the real s.d win%.

Comment: The results are consistent with approximately 1 season. On the 38% - if that's actually what the 38% represents then the description in the linked article is wrong. In fact I think that description in the linked article is probably wrong in any case.

Comment: This blog post may be of some interest: http://blog.philbirnbaum.com/2006/08/finding-true-talent-level-for-outcome.html

Comment: The author says the 38% comes from "Run a coin toss - a 30-team league, all teams .500 teams.  Look at s.d. of win % vs actual s.d of win % in the NHL".  At the time he would have had 5 season to run it on.  he also referenced that link Michael Lugo linked to, in the comments.  We know the outcome, we know the talent and it's a matter of finding the luck.  The luck = 38%.  I am going to calculate the s.d on the 5 seasons of data at the time.  The s.d of win% over the last 7 season (not including this shortened one) is 0.09346346

Comment: I am not sure how he got the 38%.  He wrote this in late 2010, he would have 5 seasons of data since the lockout.  In 5 seasons the s.d of win% was 0.09006 and the calculated win% s.d is 0.024693.  0.024693/0.09006 != 38%.  If he calculated it on 1 season 2009-2010 (too small of a sample size imo) - s.d of win% is 0.085216.  win% of calculated season is 1/sqrt(4*82) = 0.055216 = 0.647954 which is the skill % of results, luck would be 1-0.647954 != .038 (but close).  So I am not sure how he calculated the 38%, or what the real number would be.

Comment: I am not sure where the 38% comes from either. In any case, I think I've covered what you asked about in your Q, but if I didn't please clarify.

Comment: Nope, my original question was answered perfectly.  Much appreciated, you've put me on the right track.